# $PWD and $WORKSPACE are different in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-cli

My job has a build step **Build - Execute shell**, I only put these two command in:

```
echo $WORKSPACE
echo $PWD
```

And the output really confused me:

```
+ echo /home/jenkins/workspace/tradefed/test_deployment
/home/jenkins/workspace/tradefed/test_deployment
+ echo /media/d/workspace/tradefed/test_deployment
/media/d/workspace/tradefed/test_deployment
```

Why the value of `$WORKSPACE` and `$PWD` are different ?

**Update 2019/03/18:**

As @PavelAnikhouski mentioned, `$WORKSPACE` is set relatively to your `$JENKINS_HOME`, `$PWD` is OS environment variable, refers to current working directory in file system, so **they should not be the same**.

But I am still confused about `$WORKSPACE`, why Jenkins has `$WORKSPACE`, but execute shell in another working directory ?

Comment: Why they should be the same? One variable is "The absolute path of the directory assigned to the build as a workspace", second one is the your Linux OS working directory

Comment: Would you mind explaining more detail ? What's the difference between `the workspace of build` and `my Linux working directory` ?

Comment: You can see the list of Jenkins env variables at http://your_server_address/env-vars.html/ They are managed by Jenkins service itself. $WORKSPACE is set relatively to your $JENKINS_HOME (where Jenkins is installed) $PWD is OS environment variable, refers to current working directory in file system. I would not expect these values to be the same

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I see, thank you. But I am still confused about `$WORKSPACE`. Why Jenkins needs `$WORKSPACE`, but execute shell in another working directory ?

Comment: Actually they are the same for me, at least initially. I would expect the shell to start out in the project's workspace directory. You may change that by doing a `cd /some/other/place` but it makes sense as a default. Is there something else in your script that is changing which directory you're in?

Comment: @d512 I didn't do anything in the script except `echo`. I have some settings in `Source Code Management - Git` and `Gerrit Tigger`, but I didn't specify any path or change directory.