# How to change default working directory of docker container building on Jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins, devops

I'm trying to build Docker image from jenkins pipeline and it is building successfully, but when I try to inspect working directory of newly built image, it is showing as root(/) eventhough in last step of docker build pwd is /home/node/app/test. Any Suggetions?

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM opensuse-base:15.5-0086

ENV TEST_USER=test
ENV TEST_GROUP=test
ENV TEST_UID=1999
ENV TEST_GID=1999
ENV TEST_HID=1002     
ENV VAULT_VERSION=1.15.0

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /home/node/app/test

ENV export TERM=xterm
ENV export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

# Opensuse Zypper package manager
RUN zypper --non-interactive update
RUN zypper --non-interactive install vim npm

# Install Openjdk
RUN zypper --non-interactive install java-17-openjdk
RUN export JAVA_HOME=$(java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 > /dev/null | grep 'java.home' | awk '{print $3}') && \
    echo "export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME" >> /etc/profile && \
    echo "export PATH=\$PATH:\$JAVA_HOME/bin" >> /etc/profile

ENV JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}

##TEST_HID is the Docker group ID of the host machine

RUN groupadd -f ${TEST_GROUP} -g ${TEST_GID} && \
    useradd ${TEST_USER} --comment "TEST User" --uid ${TEST_UID} --gid ${TEST_GID} --create-home --home-dir /home/${TEST_USER} --shell /bin/bash && \
    groupadd -g  ${TEST_HID} docker && \
    usermod -aG docker ${TEST_USER} ;

RUN chown -R ${TEST_USER}:${TEST_GROUP} testdist

EXPOSE 3000
# ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "./entrypoint.sh"]
USER ${TEST_USER}
RUN pwd
CMD node server
```

Jenkins Logs:

```
#13 [9/11] RUN groupadd -f TEST -g 1999 &&     useradd TEST --comment "TEST User" --uid 1999 --gid 1999 --create-home --home-dir /home/TEST --shell /bin/bash &&     groupadd -g  1002 docker &&     usermod -aG docker TEST ;
#13 0.891 Group 'mail' not found. Creating the user mailbox file with 0600 mode.
#13 DONE 1.0s

#14 [10/11] RUN chown -R TEST:TEST mfsigndist
#14 DONE 1.1s

#15 [11/11] RUN pwd
#15 0.822 /home/node/app/test
#15 DONE 0.9s

#16 exporting to image
#16 exporting layers
#16 exporting layers 6.9s done
#16 writing image sha256:5277a1c0323786742f377d2164b28335ef9daed04817a5950ff3448d50346525 done
#16 naming to docker.io/library/test-sign-pr:1666 0.0s done
#16 DONE 6.9s
+ docker run --rm test-sign-pr:1666 pwd
/
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // container
```

[Screenshot is HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78RXC.png)
Note: altered some key words in the logs. Works as expected when you build on local.

Comment: In the final logs, you're building an image named `test-sign-pr` but running `test-pr`; do these names match in reality?

Comment: Yes it is the same image. Typo while replacing some key words.

Comment: `WORKDIR /home/node/app/test` so change it? The default workdir is `/`. You are most probably running a different image.

Comment: Sounds related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55178059/pwd-and-workspace-are-different-in-jenkins. Can you see if `$WORKSPACE` is /home/node/app/test?